# Efficient loop in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

I see that there are many ways to loop in JS but i'm used with PHP style so my code looks like:

```
let   tickers = ['BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC','CELR/BTC',....] // comes as object from API
const exclude = ['MATIC', 'CELR']
Object.keys(tickers).map(function(key) {
    for (var base in exclude) {
        if ( key.includes(exclude[base]) ) {
            delete tickers[key]
        }
    }
})
```

expected tickers = ['BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC',....]

The code works, but there are more efficient ways to do this in JS?

Comment: do you have some value for `tickers` and `exclude`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but `includes()` is an array method and `key` is a string

Comment: `filter` will probably be a better alternative.

Comment: @slebetman There is a `String.prototype.includes` as well.

Comment: includes works for strings as well, hence the question for data.

Comment: What is the actual usecase you are trying to solve here? The code as is is okay (you don't have to `.map` though, `.forEach` would be enough), the only way to make it more efficient would be to improve the algorithm itself (and for that, we need to know what you are actually trying to do)

Comment: Could you add some example `tickers` that are excluded?

Comment: added example and expected return

Comment: `Object.keys(tickers)` will return the values `"0", "1", "2"`... which will never contain(includes()) the string "BTC/USDT"

Comment: i know but tickers comes as object hence the Object.keys

Comment: To clarify my comment above. "key" will have the value "0", "1" .... What you are trying to do is `if ( "1".includes("MATIC") )` -- which will always be false because there is no integer that will ever include the string "MATIC"

Comment: @calcu Then show an example structure of the object. You are showing it as array

Comment: @calcu If you don't know how to generate the sample structure of `tickers` then do `console.log(JSON.stringify(tickers, null, 4))` -- the 4 is indentation level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If “comes as object from API” means you actually get

```
{'BTC/USDT': …, 'ETH/BTC': …, 'CELR/BTC': …, …}
```

and not what you showed in the question,

```
['BTC/USDT', 'ETH/BTC', 'CELR/BTC', …]
```

then `delete` and `Object.keys` are fine, though you:

- shouldn’t use `map` for side-effects (and especially not exclusively for side-effects) – `forEach` is just as compatible
- shouldn’t use `for…in` loops to iterate over arrays like `exclude`

Since you’re using `let`/`const`, there’s a good chance that `for…of` and `Object.entries` are available:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tickers)) {
    for (const base of exclude) {
        if (key.includes(base)) {
            delete tickers[key]
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you’re looking to replace the inner loop with something that doesn’t take time proportional to the size of the exclude list and given that you seem to be able to extract a list of candidates to check from a key by splitting on `/`, you can use a set as described in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

As you do have arrays here, there are better ways to iterate them, using object methods on arrays is quite inefficient. Also using `delete` you create a sparse array, that is probably not wanted. Instead you could just filter out the tickers where some of the excludes are included (that way you also avoid having a sparse array):

```
  tickers = tickers.filter(ticker => !exclude.some(other => ticker.includes(other)));
```

As you asked for efficient code though, you could create a Set of excludes and check for an exact match of the first part of the ticker (before the /):

```
  const excludeSet = new Set(exclude);

  tickers = tickers.filter(ticker => !excludeSet.has(ticker.substr(0, ticker.indexOf("/"))));
```

(wether that works depends on the exact rules you have)

Comment: The rule is to exclude any pair that is in exclude, no matter the position BTC/USD USD/BTC

Comment: @calcu but It'll always be one of the parts? So an exclude will never be "BTC/USD", but e.g. "USD" also has to exclude "BTC/USD" ?

Comment: @JonasWilms right, the tickers always come in currency pairs separated by `/` but the list of excludes are single currencies

Answer (score 0):

You asked for efficient, so you should be looking at [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which provides `O(1)` look-up times.

The following program will exclude any ticker where either currency matches an excluded value. For example, excluding `CELR` will remove `CELR/BTC` and `FOO/CELR` below -

```js
const filterTickers = (excludes = [], tickers = []) => {
  const s = new Set(excludes)
  return tickers.filter(t => t.split('/').every(x => !s.has(x)))
}

const result =
  filterTickers(['MATIC', 'CELR'], ['BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC','CELR/BTC','FOO/CELR'])

console.log(result)
// [ "BTC/USDT", "ETH/BTC" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let   tickers = ['BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC','CELR/BTC',....];
const exclude = ['MATIC', 'CELR'];
```

For reducing the function you can use [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof) methods

```
tickers = tickers.filter((ticker, i) => exclude.every((v) =>  ticker.indexOf(v) == -1));
```

```js
let   tickers = ['BTC/USDT','ETH/BTC','CELR/BTC'];
const exclude = ['MATIC', 'CELR'];

tickers = tickers.filter((ticker, i) => exclude.every((v) =>  ticker.indexOf(v) == -1));

console.log(tickers)
```

> The 'every' method executes the provided callback function once for
>   each element present in the array until it finds one where callback
>   returns a falsy value (a value that becomes false when converted to a
>   Boolean). If such an element is found, the every method immediately
>   returns false. Otherwise, if callback returned a true value for all
>   elements, every will return true. callback is invoked only for indexes
>   of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes
>   which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.([Taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every))